# При "склеивании" трех датафреймов Pandas в итоговом датафрейме появляются лишние столбцы. Не могу понять в чем причина

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет!
Есть три excel файла. Мне нужно собрать из них один датафрейм (в каждом файле 22 столбца и разное количество строк). Вроде бы элементарная задача, но итоговый файл получается непонятной размерности - откуда-то добавляются три лишних столбца.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем дело.
Код (для исключение ошибок и наглядности все три файла импортирую в отдельные датафреймы, а потом сливаю в один):

```
file1  = pd.read_excel(directory+'PH7_2015_04-05.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Данные',skiprows = 5, usecols = "A:V")
file2 = pd.read_excel(directory+'PH7_2015_06-08.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Данные', skiprows = 5, usecols = "A:V")
file3 = pd.read_excel(directory+'PH7_2015_09.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Данные', skiprows = 5, usecols = "A:V")
print(file1.shape, file2.shape, file3.shape)

# Результат - (87840, 22) (132482, 22) (29281, 22)
```

Теперь сливаю в один и столбцов становится 25(!)

```
    file_final = pd.concat([file1,file2,file3], ignore_index = True)
    file_final.shape
    # Результат - (249603, 25)
```

Прошу помочь разобраться, откуда берется лишние столбцы.

[Вот ссылка на файлы с сэмплами данных](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Q5lYeFb8ehpgVw)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Напечатайте `.columns` у исходных датафреймов и у результирующего, и сразу всё станет понятно.

Comment: Исправился. В конце первого сообщения добавил ссылку на архив c сэмплами файлов-исходников и с сэмплом результирующего датафрейма

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой результат получается при несовпадении столбцов - вот пример:

```
In [192]: d1
Out[192]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [193]: d2
Out[193]:
   a  b  d
0  7  8  9

In [194]: pd.concat([d1, d2], ignore_index = True)
Out[194]:
   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  3.0  NaN
1  4  5  6.0  NaN
2  7  8  NaN  9.0
```

Для того, чтобы решить вашу задачу - определитесь что вы хотите получить в результате и приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных и желаемый результат.

---

Для приведенных по ссылке данных - следующие столбцы не присутствуют во **всех** фреймах:

```
In [221]: all_cols = d1.columns.union(d2.columns).union(d3.columns)

In [222]: all_cols.difference(d1.columns)
Out[222]: Index(['бар.5', 'бар.6', 'гр. С.4'], dtype='object')

In [223]: all_cols.difference(d2.columns)
Out[223]: Index(['бар.6', 'мм.2', 'мм.3'], dtype='object')

In [224]: d1.columns.difference(d2.columns)
Out[224]: Index(['мм.2', 'мм.3'], dtype='object')

In [229]: d1.columns.difference(d3.columns)
Out[229]: Index(['Unnamed: 21', 'мм.2', 'мм.3'], dtype='object')

In [230]: d2.columns.difference(d3.columns)
Out[230]: Index(['Unnamed: 21'], dtype='object')

In [231]: d2.columns.difference(d1.columns)
Out[231]: Index(['бар.5', 'гр. С.4'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Прошу извинить, не сообразил прикрепить пример файлов с данными. Исправился. 
В конце первого сообщения добавил ссылку на архив с сэмплами файлов-исходников, csv - сэмплы датафреймов соответствующие каждому исходному файлу и кусок результирующего датафрейма (его для наглядности создал через file_final.sample())